# MySQL get number of records in each day between two given dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I'm writing this query where it gets a row value and it will return the number of records for each day for that row between two given dates and returns 0 if there is no records for that day.

I've written a query which does this for the past week.

Current Query:

```
select d.day, count(e.event) as count
                      from ( 
                            select 0 day union all 
                            select 1 union all 
                            select 2 union all 
                            select 3 union all 
                            select 4 union all
                            select 5 union all 
                            select 6 
                           ) d 
                      left join event e
                           on e.timestamp >= current_date - interval d.day day
                           and e.timestamp < current_date - interval (d.day - 1) day 
                           and e.event = ?
                      group by d.day
```

The problem is this returns only the results for a fixed number of days.. I want to be able to give it two dates (start and end dates) and get the record counts for each day where I don't know the number of dates in between.

Comment: The best solution is not to try to select something that is not in the database. Select what you have and fill the gaps in your program logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use/create a bona-fide calendar table.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    d.day,
    COUNT(e.timestamp) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT '2020-01-01' AS day UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020-01-02' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT '2020-12-31'
) d
LEFT JOIN event e
    ON e.timestamp >= d.day AND e.timestamp < DATE_ADD(d.day, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE
    d.day BETWEEN <start_date> AND <end_date>
GROUP BY
    d.day;
```

I have covered only the calendar year 2020, but you may extend to cover whatever range you want.

Comment: Is it possible to make it year generic?

Comment: The easiest way (IMHO) would be to just add whatever years you want.  It is best practice to stores full dates in SQL, not just month/day components.  There is also the issue of leap years, since February may have 28 or 29 days depending on the year; you really want the full date here.

Comment: But on this way, let's say if you store 10 years of date on the date table and make the left join. When you do a ```SELECT * FROM date_table```, you are gonna be selecting enormous amount of rows for just one processing?

Comment: Storing 10 years of data means about 4K dates, which should only require a few KB of storage space.  Calendar tables of dates are fairly lightweight.

Comment: I just tried making a date table and running your query.. But it returns only the non zero rows..

Comment: I was able to get it done with a little tweaking! Thanks!

Comment: @ClutchPrince You don't really need a calendar table but the overhead of maintaining one with all dates from pre-history until the sun implodes is fairly minimal

Comment: @Strawberry I was concerned about the amount of time it takes to execute the query, but it was very less! Everything is solved now!